# I need some help on the intuition behind polar form of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm working on a problem right now where I have the complex number $z = \cos(20) + i\sin(20)$, and finding the number $w$ such that $w^2 = z$

So, I know $w^2 = \cos(2t) + i\sin(2t)$, I'm not *exactly* sure why - I did the arithmetic to arrive at the conclusion so I know it's right, but I'm not sure geometrically why it's correct.

I then decided that I was really, then, solving the problem of all $t : 2t = 20\mod{180}$ which is really $t = 10 \mod 180$ which gives me the set $t = \{10, 190, 370, ... \}$ (yes I know there are negative numbers, too!) and I couldn't figure out geometrically why using 180 instead of 360 makes sense. It seems to me that moving $t$ to 190 should give me $a, b < 0$ and I don't understand how that angle is the same.

I plugged the values into Wolfram and it verified that my equations are right, but I'm not sure why I can use $180$ degrees.

Comment: $2 \cdot t$ is $2(10+180k)=20+360k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a grasp on the fact the multiplication of complex numbers is a rotation on the complex plane.

That is, if the lenths are $1,$ then multplication simply adds the angles.

$(\cos x + i \sin x)(\cos y + i \sin y) = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y + i(\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y) = (\cos(x+y) + i \sin (x+y))$

$w = (\cos 10^\circ + i \sin 10^\circ) \implies w^2= (\cos 20^\circ + i \sin 20^\circ)$

But what about $(-w)^2$?

$(-w)^2 = (-1)^2 w^2 = w^2$

Suggesting that:

$(-\cos 10^\circ - i \sin 10^\circ)^2 = (\cos 20^\circ + i \sin 20^\circ)$

$\cos(\theta + 180^\circ) = -\cos\theta$ and $\sin(\theta + 180^\circ) = -\sin(\theta)$

$(-\cos 10^\circ - i \sin 10^\circ) = (\cos 190^\circ  +i \sin 190^\circ)$

and

$(\cos 190^\circ + i \sin 190^\circ)^2 = (\cos 380^\circ + i \sin 380^\circ) = (\cos 20^\circ + i \sin 20^\circ)$

Comment: Awesome, this perfectly answers my question. I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking about de Moivre's theorem. Well, in a sense.

When you consider the multiplication of two complex numbers, you have some sort of rotation happening. How? Let

$$ z = re^{i\theta} = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) $$

be a complex number. Take another complex number

$$ w = Re^{i\phi} = R(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi) $$

and watch what happens if we multiply the two in their exponential form.

\begin{align*}
zw &= (re^{i\theta})(Re^{i\phi}) \\
&= rRe^{i(\theta + \phi)}
\end{align*}

This just reduces to adding $\arg z$ and $\arg w$ together! In particular, taking powers of a complex number is just adding that same argument to itself (as well as taking powers of the modulus).

Comment: Absolutely. I guess specifically I'm getting tripped up when I think about the negative options for the angles. If I had that issue, would I just need to shift it back into positive values? And also - how does this allow me to use 180 degrees as the modulus for solving the powers? 

EDIT: I feel like it has to do with the fact that the angles add together in polar form.

Comment: If you would like to do that, then yes. Everything still works out.

Answer (score 0):

You need only use the polar form you refer to, for
$$
z = \cos(x) + i\sin(x) = e^{ix},
$$
thus if $w^2 = z$ then $e^{ix} = w^2$ or 
$$w = e^{ix/2} = \cos(x/2) + i\sin(x/2).$$
You can simply put $x = 20^\circ$ in this equation to find $w$ (though be warned that radians are often preferable to degrees). Everything you have derived comes from this sort of reasoning.